# Magento: save custom address attribute in checkout

Tags: php, checkout, magento

This is what i did in my website: Admin->Customers->Attributes->Manage Customer Address Attributes and add a new attribute , the user can see it in his/her profile, under My Addresses option, the new attribute can be edited and is saved when creating a new address, i also can see it in the backend, and edited, until here everything is ok, my problem is in the checkout, i already have the field in the billing and shipping forms and i want the new attribute to be saved when the user click "Place Order" button, but, checkout seems it doesn't know nothing about the new attribute, the attribute is not saved and if i save one value from the user profile checkout doesn't load it in the field.

what can i do here??

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking in the Magento's code and reading the wiki, I was able to complete it, my new attribute was saved in the address edit form in the profile, but was not saved when I enter it in the checkout form, that was because I need to override some Magento core files, the first step was adding the new attribute to `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\etc\config.xml`, I copied to `app\code\core\Mycompany\Customer\etc\config.xml`, as my new attribute code is **rfc**, I located the `<fieldsets>` entry and

```
<customer_dataflow>
    ....
    <rfc><billing>1</billing><shipping>1</shipping></rfc>
</customer_dataflow>
```

now I need to add the new attribute to the `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Entity\Setup.php` i did the same to override, copied to my local namespace, and in the function `getDefaultEntities()` i locate the

```
'customer_address'=>array(
    ....
            'rfc' => array(
            'label'         => 'RFC',
            'required'      => false,
            'sort_order'    => 135,
    ),
)
```

now, I need to do also the same in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\etc\config.xml`, but now should look like this

```
<sales_copy_order_billing_address>
    .....
    <rfc><to_order>*</to_order></rfc>
</sales_copy_order_billing_address>

<sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
    ......
    <rfc><to_order>*</to_order></rfc>
</sales_copy_order_shipping_address>

<sales_convert_quote_address>
    ........
    <rfc><to_order_address>*</to_order_address><to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address></rfc>
</sales_convert_quote_address>

<sales_convert_order_address>
    .........
    <rfc><to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address></rfc>
</sales_convert_order_address>

<customer_address>
    .......
    <rfc><to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address></rfc>
</customer_address>
```

Hope it can help someone else