# magento custom order attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, orders

i'm trying to add some custom attributes to the checkout(sales) page of magento 1.5.1.0 for orders created from the backend (administrator) panel.
I tried this code and i can see my new attribute in the eav_attribute table, but i can't see my new attribute when i make an order from the backend.
What am i missing..?

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('5', 'testattr', array(
 'label' => 'testlabel',
 'type' => 'varchar',
 'input' => 'text',
 'visible' => true,
 'required' => false,
 'position' => 5,
 ));


$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('5', 'testattr');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('checkout_register', 'adminhtml_checkout'));
$attribute->save();
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks clockworkgeek for your replies. I found the solution by using some extra address attributes instead because it was a lot more easier (i had to search a lot though).

so the solution is..

```
<?php 

//Attribute to add
$newAttributeName = "rfc"; //modify this with the name of your attribute

//a) Add EAV Attributes (modify as you needed)
$attribute  = array(
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'RFC',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'user_defined'  => true,
    'searchable'    => false,
    'filterable'    => false,
    'comparable'    => false,
);

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
//Add to customer
$setup->addAttribute('customer_address', $newAttributeName, $attribute);


/* this is not working for some reason. add the columns manually
//b) Add Quote attributes (one page step to step save field)
$setup = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup('sales_setup');
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable('sales_flat_quote_address'),
        $newAttributeName,
        'text NULL DEFAULT NULL'
    );
$setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
$setup->getTable('sales_flat_order_address'),
$newAttributeName,
        'text NULL DEFAULT NULL'
);
*/
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $newAttributeName);
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer_address',
                'adminhtml_checkout_address')); //'customer_register_address', 'customer_address_edit',
$attribute->save();


?>
```

and then edit the files according to this post.
[Magento: save custom address attribute in checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609987/magento-save-custom-address-attribute-in-checkout)

Answer (score 3):

Order entities are awkwardly not like normal entities, they use a flat table instead of EAV, which means that it's not enough to just assign an attribute. You must alter the flat table [(which I tried here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370235/saving-extra-data-with-an-order-in-magento) or create additional tables then join them to the flat table. With hindsight I see I should have taken the second option, it's safer.

---

I've been looking a bit closer at the order template and there might a hackish sort of workaround via a lesser used block. To start with let's make changes in a `layout/local.xml` file so it's safe from overwriting by upgrades;

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="gift_options">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" template="YOUR/TEMPLATE.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

The gift options block is constructed in an open-ended way so adding to it is relatively easy. Obviously replace `YOUR/TEMPLATE.phtml` with the path of a file you will create. The template being inserted needs to have input fields with names like `order[testattr]` and those *should* be copied directly to the database table (according to `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create`, if I am reading the source code right). The gift options block already creates a `<fieldset>` inside the order's `<form>` so only the input fields are needed.

Comment: I tried to add a new column to the sales_flat_order and sales_flat_quote but i can't see any new attributes when i create a new order from administration panel.

Comment: Form fields are not automatic either, you need to add to the template. It's not as easy as product nor customer entities.

Comment: I searched a lot but couldn't find anything to help me out..
Some links that looked relevant was for adding attributes for the onepagecheckout, but i want for the adminhtml..
i know that the code must be in here "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/data.phtml" but i dont know what..

I could add the attributes i need to another place (e.g the customers address) do you think that this is easier..?
Thanks..

Comment: I've updated my answer with the layout-based method I would attempt. Using the customer address entity could work too, addresses are copied to another table (`sales_flat_order_address`) so it would be specific to each order and not alter the actual customer's address. Because it is also a flat table it too would need new columns added.